# using SWITCH() Formula in Google Sheets using hash-map

Tags: google-sheets

In my Google Sheet table, I use [SWITCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en) command to convert a cell from `coin symbol` -> into `coin value`.

**what I currently do:**

```
=SWITCH(D660,"₪","ILS","$","USD","Ft","HUF","€","EUR","лв","BGN","£","EGP")
```

this will convert cell `D660` from coin symbol (`₪/$/Ft/€/лв/£`) -> into `coin name`

here's an example of my data:

[image]

where in column `E` I have the equation above.

**what I want to do:**

I want to a more generic way, where I have a "hash-map" table in my `Settings` tab which contains the following table:

| coin_symbol | coin_name |
| --- | --- |
| ₪ | ILS |
| $ | USD |
| Ft | HUF |
| € | EUR |
| лв | BGN |
| £ | EGP |

and now I want the `=SWITCH(D660,...)` to use the table instead of hard coding inserting the conversion table

.

I'm struggling on this one, I tried stuffs like
`=SWITCH(D660,A1:A10,B1:B10)` or involving `ARRAYFORMULA` somewhere but nothing worked.

anyone have a suggestion how to implement that?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 thanks for the feedback, added. hope that makes it more clear

Comment: For future reference:

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VLOOKUP()`

In table with the coins symbols and value as you described ( where symbols is column A and name column B)

```
=VLOOKUP([SYMBOL];[A1:B6];2;FALSE)
```

Where:
`Symbol` is the symbol you want to replace ( you can use cell reference );
`A1:B6` is the table you want to look in;
`2` is the column in wich you take the value;
`False` as the values are not ordered by a number, just use false.

**/!\ depending on your locatioon the `;` in my formula might have to be replaced by `,`**

[Here's an example you could use](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/112cEPxZwk4wVKY9sobSVHdl7cerx-JSNDaWxZk28cPk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Nice! so elegant! totally forgot about vlookup, Thank you so much!!